# Internet download speed is lower than usual but surfing speed is fine

Tags: internet, speed

I have a 512 kbps connection. I should receive approx 60 kBps download speed. But from last 2-3 days I am getting only 20 kBps of download speed.

But I don't see any difference in speed while surfing. What might be the problem?  Happens with all downloads. Torrent, from youtube ( through jdownloader ), normal files with and without download manager.

Comment: Downloading what with what, when?

Comment: all things ... torrent , from youtube ( through jdownloader ) , normal files with and without download manager

Comment: Does your ISP throttle (have they started)? Does it matter what time?

Comment: throttle means ???

Comment: Throttle means to slow traffic to a user(s) often based on content.  So torrents may be slowed but regular browsing is OK.

Comment: Most ISPs these days also slow traffic based on time-of-day. They oversell their services and so when there is a lot of traffic during peak hours (eg during business hours—for some reason), they slow everybody’s traffic to balance it out. See if your speeds are still low at night.